# achilles Cassandra mock server: no libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib in java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, cassandra, sigar

I use a [archilles cassandra mock server](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles) to perform unit testing for my java maven project and everything works fine except I get an exception printed out in the console:

> org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib
>   in java.library.path  at
>   org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)   at
>   org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.(Sigar.java:100)  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.SigarLibrary.(SigarLibrary.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.SigarLibrary.(SigarLibrary.java:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks$7.execute(StartupChecks.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks.verify(StartupChecks.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
>     at
>   info.archinnov.achilles.embedded.ServerStarter.lambda$start$0(ServerStarter.java:164)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This problem does influence the test results but I don't like to see it in the console, especially because my colleagues are likely to see it when they perform maven install.

I have seen some solutions to this problem however they involve local  configurations in my machine (e.g. manually adding a jar file to some local directory). This is not an option because I don't want my colleagues to reproduce this problem and I don't want to force them to do those configurations.

Therefore, I am looking for a fix that involves only the project itself (e.g. add one or more dependencies to my pom.xml to make this exception go away), so that the next pulled version of my project from the repository does not print this exception during build, without any local configuration.

Thank you for your help.